# No <div> and "label for=" tags in my code, but it seems to work fine?

Tags: html, forms

I'm new. Just trying to learn HTML. I was working on forms and made a "build a donut" form using a couple of different forms. Everything seems to work fine. 
But I saw someone else's project that also dealt with forms and their code was full of `div` tags where I have breaks and `label for=`. 
So I'm just looking for feedback. Do I need the extra tags to be technically correct? Here's my code:

```html
<!doctype>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Create Your Own Donuts</title>
</head>

<h2>Fill Out The Form Below To Create Your Order</h2>


<style type="text/css">
  body {
    background-color: #d2b48c;
    margin-left: 30%;
    margin-right: 30%;
    border: 2px solid black;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
  }
</style>


<body>


  <p>
    Choose Donut Base:
    <select type="Base">
      <option value="Base"> Cake</option>
      <option value="Base"> Yeast</option>
    </select>
  </p>


  <p>
    Choose A Shape:
    <select type="Topping">
      <option value="Glazed">Rectangle</option>
      <option value="Chocolate">Disk</option>
      <option value="Powdered">Ball</option>
    </select>
  </p>

  <p>
    Choose Your Filling: <br>
    <input type="radio" name="filling" value="jelly">Jelly<br>
    <input type="radio" name="filling" value="cream">Cream<br>
    <input type="radio" name="filling" value="none">None<br>

  </p>

  <p>
    Toppings:
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="toppings" vaule="Blueberries">Blueberries
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="toppings" value="Shredded Coconut">Shredded Coconut
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="toppings" value="Caramel Drizzle">Caramel Drizzle
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="toppings" value="Strawberries">Strawberries
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="toppings" value="Marshmallows">Marshmallows
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="toppings" value="Crushed Oreos">Crushed Oreos
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="toppings" value="Coffee Crisp">Coffee Crisps
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="toppings" value="Whipped Cream">Whipped Cream
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="toppings" value="Hot Fudge">Hot Fudge
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="toppings" value="Crushed Graham Crackers">Crushed Graham Crackers
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="toppings" value="Sprinkles">Sprinkles
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="toppings" value="Powdered Sugar">Powdered Sugar
    <br>

  </p>

  <p>

    Hot or Cold: <br>
    <input type="radio" name="Sprinkles" value="Yes">Hot <br>
    <input type="radio" name="Sprinkles" value="No">Cold

  </p>

  <p>

    Quantity:
    <input type="number" min="1" max="100">
  </p>

  <p>

    Name:
    <input type="Name" placeholder="Name" required><br> Email: <input type="email" placeholder="example@gmail.com"><br> Phone Number: <input type="tel" placeholder="555.55.55" required>
    <br> Pickup Date: <input type="date"> <br> Pickup Time: <input type="time">

  </p>

  <p>

    <button input type="submit">Place Order</button>

  </p>



   </body>



</html>
```

Comment: You can read about the `label` element here, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label. `No` would be the answer to the question you asked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see, your code seems to work just fine without label tags. However, when creating a form, you should always use label and input tags. They belong together and it's important for accessability reasons.

Have you ever noticed when filling out a form, that you can just click on the label and it fills the checkbox or the radio button. You can achieve this by using label tags that have as their `for` attribute whatever the corresponding input tag has as an id. So for example:

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="toppings" vaule="Blueberries" id="blueberries">
<label for="blueberries">Blueberries</label>
```

Now you can click on the label and the checkbox gets filled. Visually impaired users that use screenreaders also rely on that behaviour.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Super helpful information. Also, I clarified a little more in my post about the missing <div> tags, but if that is still incorrect please let me know!

Comment: So yes, for the div tags, those are "just" boxes. But as you will move on in learning, you will see that you use them a lot for styling as well as positioning. You shoulnd't just add them, only when you need to, your `<br>` are fine!

Comment: Thank you very much!